# append field value in inline json array object in mongo through kafka mongo sink connector

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

publish first insertion :

`{"Customer_id": 2, "transaction_id": "1", "idd": [999, 1111], "id": 1}`

and then second one :

`{"Customer_id": 2, "transaction_id": "2", "idd": [9, 10], "id": 1}`

required result :

`{"Customer_id": 2, "transaction_id": "2", "idd": [[9, 10] , [999, 1111]], "id": 1}`

what i get:

`{"Customer_id": 2, "transaction_id": "2", "idd": [9, 10] , "id": 1}`

update strategy this update array not append but my expected result to append array

configuration :

```
document.id.strategy=com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.processor.id.strategy.PartialValueStrategy
value.projection.list=customer_id,transaction_id
value.projection.type=whitelist
writemodel.strategy=com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.writemodel.strategy.ReplaceOneBusinessKeyStrategy
```

how can we do this through mongo-kafka sink connector

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to aggregate streaming data

Unless MongoDB somehow is able to provide this functionality via inserting the same document ID (which I doubt because how does it know that you only want to collect the idd field?), you would have to use Kafka Streams / KSQL or another stateful processing layer, to aggregate your values. The sink connector just forwards whatever it sees into the database ; the connector has no knowledge of previous records